# I am trying install bokeh library in python but the error occurred. Now the pip is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\S\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
File "c:\users\s\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line 21, in <module>
from pip._vendor.packaging.utils import canonicalize_name
```

`ValueError`: source code string cannot contain `null bytes`

Comment: if you run `python -m pip --version` what do you get

Comment: get same error for python -m pip --version.

Comment: assuming your python3 path are correct try to reinstall pip by running `sudo apt install --reinstall python-pip` then try again `python -m pip --version`

Comment: @Orenico I think he is on Windows...

Comment: @Orenico Thank You. Actually your method is working. But I am in Windows. Anyways I got it.